# Does Pagination require it's own controller?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, typescript

Sorry, angular newbie.  I've been playing all day and can't get my pagination to respond to the data.  There just doesn't seem to be any link between my directive and the content.  Can I put the pagination information in the same controller as the one used on the rest of the page?  I'm trying to limit my list of objects to five per page.  I copied the code from JS and tried to convert it to typescript, which may be a problem as well.

Here's my controller:

```
export class HomeController {
    public challenges;
    public challengesCompleted;
    //public allCompletedChallenges;
    public totalItems = 1;
    public currentPage = 1;
    public maxSize = 1;
    public bigTotalItems = 1;
    public bigCurrentPage = 1;
    public setPage(pageNo) {
        this.currentPage = pageNo;
    };



    constructor
        (
        private challengeService: MyApp.Services.ChallengeService,
        private $location: angular.ILocationService,
        $routeParams: ng.route.IRouteParamsService
        ) {
        this.challenges = this.challengeService.listChallenges();
        this.challengesCompleted = this.challengeService.list10FinishedChallenges();
        this.maxSize = 5;
        this.bigTotalItems = 5;
        this.bigCurrentPage = 5;

        //this.allCompletedChallenges = this.challengeService.listAllCompletedChallenges();
    }


}
```

and html:

```
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="challenge in controller.challenges  | filter: globalSearch">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4>
                                    Created By: {{challenge.challenger}}
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4>{{challenge.dateCreated  | date: 'longDate'}}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4>Title: <b>{{challenge.title}}</b></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4>Bet Amount: {{challenge.amount}}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h4>
                                    Description
                                </h4>
                                {{challenge.description}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <a ng-hide="challenge.challengee!=null || !account.isLoggedIn() || account.getDisplayName() == challenge.challenger" href="/acceptChallenge/{{challenge.id}}"><b>ACCEPT THIS CHALLENGE!</b></a>
                                <a ng-show="!account.isLoggedIn() && challenge.challengee == null" href="/login"><b>YOU MUST BE LOGGED IN TO ACCEPT THIS CHALLENGE.</b></a>
                                <p ng-show="challenge.challengee!=null"><b><i>Challenge has been accepted by {{challenge.challengee}} and is in progress.</i></b></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 linebreak">

            <br />
        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><br /><br />
            </div>
                            <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="controller.currentPage" items-per-page=5 max-size="5" class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true">
                            </uib-pagination>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be using the `ng-change` attribute of the uib-pagination, you probably need to link it to the method where actual paging needs to happen

something like this,

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(){
    $scope.pagedChallanges = $scope.challanges.splice....
}
```

and probably you have to bind pagedChallanges to the view.

but better approach would be doing the paging in the server, and when page changes send a call to server to get the required page.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time!  I think I get what you're saying, but I'm using typescript.  i think a different approach is in order.

Comment: @ScottVMeyers you can just make a method in your controller class, and use controllerAs in the directive to inject the controller in the view.